# Google Drive Api does not work if I load the App in the Play Store

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play

I created an App that uses Google Drive Api, I created the OAuth 2.0 client ID credentials with the new SH1 key and if I install the APK without going through the Play Store, the connection to Google Drive works correctly.
The problem arises when I install the app via the Play Store because in this case the Google Drive APIs stop working.
can you help me? I can't really understand where the problem is ...

Comment: maybe you are using proguard in the release version on play store

Comment: Can you give me some more information? Is there any setting in the console of the play store, or do you say that I use proguard at the moment of apk generation? I repeat that the same apk that I load on the play store, if I install it manually by copying it to the device, everything works correctly.

Comment: Hi @ItaloPiscopiello, did you find a solution? I'm currently facing this problem, and I can't really understand where the problem is.